# Split a Pandas 'findall' result list into multiple items, to group by uniques

Tags: python, pandas

I've downloaded my Twitter archive and I'm trying to do some analysis on who I have talked to the most.

Tweets CSV columns look like this:

```
tweet_id,in_reply_to_status_id,in_reply_to_user_id,retweeted_status_id,retweeted_status_user_id,timestamp,source
```

I've used read_csv() to import the tweets.csv file into a dataframe called "indata".

Then, to get a list of all the @handles mentioned in tweets, I used the following:

```
handles = indata['text'].str.findall('@[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*')
```

Result:

```
timestamp
...
2013-04-12 11:24:27                                [@danbarker]
2013-04-12 11:22:32                                  [@SeekTom]
2013-04-12 10:50:45    [@33Digital, @HotwirePR, @kobygeddes, @]
2013-04-12 08:00:03                              [@mccandelish]
2013-04-12 07:59:01                                [@Mumbrella]
...
Name: text, dtype: object
```

What I'd like to be able to do is group by the individual handles and dates, to show counts of who I've spoken to the most over the years.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A purely pandas way might be to apply the Series constructor to put this into one DataFrame and stack into a Series (so you can use value_counts)... if you didn't care about the index/timestamp you could use collections (which *may* be faster):

```
In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame([['@a @b'], ['@a'], ['@c']], columns=['tweets'])

In [12]: df
Out[12]:
  tweets
0  @a @b
1     @a
2     @c

In [13]: at_mentions = df['tweets'].str.findall('@[a-zA-Z0-9_]+')
```

*Note: I'd use `+` rather than `*` here since I don't think `@` by itself should be included.*

```
In [14]: at_mentions
Out[14]:
0    [@a, @b]
1        [@a]
2        [@c]
Name: tweets, dtype: object
```

Using [collections' Counter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) this is very easy:

```
In [21]: from collections import Counter

In [22]: Counter(at_mentions.sum())
Out[22]: Counter({'@a': 2, '@b': 1, '@c': 1})
```

The pandas way will keep the index (time) information.

[`Apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) Series constructor to get a DataFrame and [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) it into a Series:

```
In [31]: all_mentions = at_mentions.apply(pd.Series)

In [32]: all_mentions
Out[33]:
    0    1
0  @a   @b
1  @a  NaN
2  @c  NaN
```

We can tidy the names here to be more descriptive about what's going on:

```
In [33]: all_mentions.columns.name = 'at_number'

In [34]: all_mentions.index.name = 'tweet'  # this is timestamp in your example
```

Now when we stack, we see the names of the levels:

```
In [35]: all_mentions = all_mentions.stack()

In [36]: all_mentions
Out[36]:
tweet  at_number
1      0            @a
       1            @b
2      0            @a
3      0            @c
dtype: object
```

We could do lots of other analysis here, for example [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
In [37]: all_mentions.value_counts()
Out[37]:
@a    2
@c    1
@b    1
dtype: int64
```

*The final result is equivalent to `pd.Series(Counter(at_mentions.sum()))`.*

Comment: Really comprehensive answer, thanks Andy. The pandas native way works for me - I like the idea of keeping the timestamps so I can group by date - but thanks for introducing me to collections.Counter too.